# Moderator deleted solution to question and then closed it :-(

Tags: discussion, moderation

This revision log doesn't make sense to me:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6497098/revisions

As I understand it: The OP asked question, then OP found a solution by himself and edited the question, adding the solution (which wasn't smart, I agree).

Then the moderator deleted the solution (which is OK) but instead of adding it as an answer, he closed the question. Now the solution will be very hard to find.

That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Adding the solution in the question doesn't help.  That's not where it goes.  If the person answered his own question, he should add an answer.

Comment: My point is that the moderator made it hard to find the solution. A solution in the question is better than no solution at all. And now, the OP can't post the solution in the correct place anymore since the question is closed.

Comment: The moderator made it hard to find the "solution" because he felt that the "solution" was not high quality and was not posted as an answer. The community of SO is free to reopen the question and then anyone can post an answer (or that answer/solution as an answer, not inside the question.)

Answer (score 12):

The question at issue here was posted a *long time ago*, and the poster of it has not been here since September of last year. There had been attempts to ask the user to post their solution as an answer, but they did not respond to those, despite having been here since.

I could have posted an answer, but considering the question, I did not. The question was basically a requirement and a very vague description of what did not work, and the answer was mostly just a code dump.

The final result appeared to count for being closed for the reason I did. I'm not at all against it being reopened by the community and answered then, though.

---

Also, incidentally; my actions were taken in the course of handling flags for moderator attention.

Comment: +1 for community reopening it. That's why the question is "on hold," and not deleted.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Precisely! :)

Comment: First of all, many people don't know what specifically to ask. So the first question often is broad but an expert will quickly see what the real problem is. This approach allows other people to find answers by using broad search terms. In this respect, I didn't think the question as "broad". He listed all the technologies he used and what he tried and that he just wanted an example. ...

Comment: Secondly, why didn't you copy the code into the answer instead of deleting it? Now we have to vote to reopen the question before we can answer it :-(

Comment: Thirdly, the code dump contains the correct answer. It's more than strictly necessary but at least it's correct. Now, we have nothing.

Comment: @AaronDigulla First of all, Stack Overflow did not invent asking *good* questions. We just are picky that people do it. Secondly, there was no existing answer, and the answer was not mine to post. Thirdly, it's not *more* than strictly necessary, IMO; it's *less*. We're not here to be a code-dump repository, but a place where people learn how to solve problems. Nothing about that question or answer does that, in my opinion.

Comment: Moderation is about weighting goals. You destroyed knowledge. Looking at the age of the question, I think OP never intended to edit the question and make it look as you wanted. Using Google, I couldn't find a single place left with the information you deleted. Taking all that into account, I  feel strongly that you did a bad job this time.

Comment: @AaronDigulla *"I think OP never intended to edit the question and make it look as you wanted"* That's actually the biggest reason I did what I did. I understand your disagreement with what I did, and appreciate your constructive way of bringing it up. That said; your post here has brought attention to it, and could result in the issue being 'fixed'.

Comment: I thought of a couple of answers but everything was basically just an insult. I hate what you did, I disagree with your reasons and I feel like I'm wasting my time here.

Comment: @AaronDigulla Well, I do appreciate your self-control there, sincerely. I can see you are very frustrated and disagree very strongly with what was done. I respect that, and I am truly sorry you feel your time was wasted. You have made a very impassioned plea.

Answer (score 10):

The question shouldn't contain the solution. The moderator acted correctly in removing the solution. The OP should have placed their solution in an answer. It seems to me that the moderator then made a judgment call to close the question as too broad. Alternatively, the moderator could have asked the OP to place their solution in an answer if it wasn't too broad of a question.

Comment: The question is too broad...the only question that remains is "should the moderator have posted the solution as answer before closing it" which I'd answer with "no".

Comment: The question isn't too broad. It's specific to the point. This feels like "Oh, i don't understand what this guy is talking about, so i just close it"

Comment: @AaronDigulla That's your opinion. The moderator has experience with making these types of judgments. In my opinion, if the question can be more specific (in this case, I think so), then it's probably too broad.

Comment: I would have preferred the moderator to wait for the OP to fix the question. Now the question is closed and OP can't do anything anymore.

Comment: The wording could be better but the question just asks: "How do I test a link with an onclick event handler?" Please explain to me how that could fit any definition of "broad".

Comment: @AaronDigulla The *purpose* of closing questions is to provide an opportunity for their author to fix them.  Saying that the author can't do anything once it is closed is completely false.  He can make the question more specific if he wants it to be reopened.

Comment: @Servy: Please be careful with your wording. A **closed** question can't be edited anymore. The question here is **on hold**. It might eventually be closed but it's not currently. That said, I had to read up on "on hold" in the help center before I understood the difference. I'll check in a few days to see how well that works in this case.

Comment: @AaronDigulla: it might have confused you, but being on hold vs closed changes nothing in regards to whether you can edit your question or not. It's just using "soft wording" to make people do something about their posts. You can still edit posts if they are closed -- only if it's locked then you won't be able to edit it.

Comment: @AaronDigulla The next step after a question is closed is for it to be deleted. The on hold period gives OP the opportunity to improve their question, at which point the question can be voted to reopen.

Comment: @AaronDigulla And yet I somehow managed to edit the question just now, despite it being closed.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO: One minor thing: There is already a comment that asks OP to put the answer in the correct place. My guess right now is that they can't because the answer is on hold.

Comment: @AaronDigulla or, they just don't care because they no longer have that problem.

Comment: @KevinB: Is that a good enough reason to destroy knowledge?

Comment: @AaronDigulla It's not really adding any value since the website is optimized (SEO) around the question being upvoted and answered. I don't understand why it's so difficult to follow the QA format.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO: Sorry, that "SEO" sentence didn't make sense for me :-/ Can you try to word that differently?

Comment: @AaronDigulla Your claim that it destroys knowledge is false since it may not appear on search engine results when future visitors attempt to search for it.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO: "Why it's so difficult to follow the QA format": 1. Most people simply aren't used to do it. The OP is a complete newbie (1 question, never came back). 2. Many people have a lot of stress at the job and want things done. Asking a good question takes time, experience and low stress levels. That's why I give them a few months to fix a problem and if that doesn't happen, I would fix it even if that meant rewriting most of the text and posting an answer. But I would never destroy knowledge just because I don't like how it's formatted.

Comment: Not sure where you're getting your facts.. 1.) OP has 5 questions; the question you're referencing was asked on Jun 27 '11 and their last visit was on Sep 16 '13. 2) Giving someone a few months to fix a problem is completely unrealistic. If you wish to grant "a few months" to fix their problem, then you must also grant 3 months for someone to answer the question. Lastly, this question does not fit the criteria of "knowledge" to me. What benefit will future visitors have? Will they understand what the OP is asking, or be left confused because it's unclear?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO: Well, it's not unclear to me. If you think you can improve it, then do it. I wouldn't have opened this meta question if the admin had simply put the code into an answer. But he chose to delete and that doesn't make sense for me.